# Opening this file in nano shows peculiar red area

Tags: text-editor, text, nano, data-corruption

I have a simple text file. When I open it with nano, there is a red area covering space in front of some of the text. I have never seen this:

[image: red and white blocks covering space before text]

What can I do about this?

Comment: Those may be tabs rather than spaces, which the syntax highlighter is making clear. I believe you can disable the highlight with [Alt]+[Y] …

Answer (score 3):

Also, in `/usr/share/nano/default.nanorc` you can comment out the section:

```
# Spaces in front of tabs
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is not just "tabs rather than spaces" as @matigo said.